# Number of bits per packet in network communication

Tags: networking

In networking, what is the relationship between the number of bits and a packet? In other words, how many bits are there in a packet? Is this number constant? If not, what does it depend on? (protocols, physical constraints...)

Thanx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each level of the TCP layer has different terminology for the "packet":

> TCP -   Segment
> IP -              Datagram
> Data Link layer - Frame
> Physical -        bits or more generic a packet

I am assuming you are asking about what eventually goes into the network.

So, the size of a frame is influenced by the **Maximum Transmission Unit (MTU)**, ie the max no of bits/packet your channel supports (channel here means multiple links/hops, MTU of the entire path is equal to the minimum of the MTUs of each hop in the path).

Since, it varies, so your packet/bit can't be constant. There are protocols employed that determine the path MTU called **Path MTU Discovery** using [ICMP message](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Control_Message_Protocol).

---

Read more:
**RFC 1191** (details how MTU for the route is determined): https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1191
**MTU on wikipedia**: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_transmission_unit